# docker-compose: my containers connect to each other but don't connect to the host

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a spring-boot app and a mongodb in two containers managed by docker-compose. The app seems to connect nicely to the mongodb, but neither of them can be reached by the outside, i.e. my local machine. I think I need some expert advice, here...

**1) installed base :**

- Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a
- docker-compose version  1.24.1, build 4667896b

**2) docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
   app:
      build: .
      restart: unless-stopped
      container_name: project-service
      ports:
         - target:  8080
           published: 8080
      networks:
         - project-net
      working_dir: /app
      depends_on:
         - db

   db:
      image: mongo
      container_name: project-db
      volumes:
         - type: volume
           source: project-data
           target: /data/db
           volume:
             nocopy: true
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
         - target: 27017
           published: 27017
      networks:
         - project-net

networks:
   project-net:

volumes:
   project-data:
```

**3) the apps Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:latest AS service
WORKDIR /src/fscl/project-service
COPY . .
RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml dependency:resolve
RUN mvn -B package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS runtime
RUN apk update && apk add bash
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=service /src/fscl/project-service/target/project-service-0.2.0.jar .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/project-service-0.2.0.jar"]
```

**4) status when running :**

$ docker-compose up &

relevant logs:

```
project-service | 2019-11-08 15:33:09.688  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[project-db:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
project-db | 2019-11-08T15:33:09.755+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:41964 #1 (1 connection now open)
project-db | 2019-11-08T15:33:09.771+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.20.0.3:41964 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.11.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-124-generic" }, platform: "Java/IcedTea/1.8.0_212-b04" }
project-service | 2019-11-08 15:33:09.809  INFO 1 --- [roject-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to project-db:27017
project-service | 2019-11-08 15:33:11.305  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
project-service | 2019-11-08 15:33:11.310  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.p.ProjectServiceApplication            : Started ProjectServiceApplication in 5.538 seconds (JVM running for 6.383)
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
aecb3d4bb468        project-service_app   "java -jar /app/proj…"   About an hour ago   Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp     project-service
257985d48264        mongo                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   project-db
```

from this I take all went well, but it didn't:

**5) The problems:**

```
 curl localhost:8080/api/v4/projects
```

should return a JSON object, but it doesn't. The app shows no logging reaction, either. Nothing ever gets through to my service app.

```
$  mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

just hangs forever

```
$  mongo project-db:27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: project-db:27017
2019-11-08T16:42:26.869+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("project-db") failed: Name or service not known
2019-11-08T16:42:26.869+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't initialize connection to host project-db, address is invalid :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

$ mongo localhost:27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: localhost:27017
```

also hangs.

I believe I have followed all the examples out there, but what in the world do I need to do different ?

Comment: What's your host OS?  What "kind" of Docker is it (in particular, is it based on Docker Machine or Docker Toolbox)?

Comment: where do you run `curl localhost:8080/api/v4/projects`? on the host? does it return expected result if you run it inside app container?

Comment: Agree with @rok to run `docker-compose exec app curl localhost:8080/api/v4/projects` and post the results. What i'd also do is use telnet to check your ports from the host `telnet localhost 8080` even though `docker ps` appears to show that the ports are mapped correctly. It wouldn't hurt to see this in the container as well.

Comment: @ David Maze: LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch

Comment: @rok, leeman: I run curl from a terminal on my host. I currently have no curl installed inside the container, but  ping inside works:  docker-compose exec app /bin/bash
bash-4.4# ping localhost:8080
PING localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
...

Comment: can you try to install curl inside the container and check?

Comment: @ rok, leeman: no telnet inside container. telnetting from host also just hangs :      $ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: @rok: Oh yeah, here it at least reacts to the call : bash-4.4# apk add curl
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.35.1-r1)
(2/4) Installing libssh2 (1.9.0-r1)
(3/4) Installing libcurl (7.64.0-r3)
(4/4) Installing curl (7.64.0-r3)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 113 MiB in 63 packages
bash-4.4# curl localhost:8080/api/v4/projects
{"errMsg":"","projects":[]}bash-4.4#

Comment: @ rok: also, docker inspect project-service shows amnong tons of other stuff  these ip adresses in the  "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3", but I note the iptables has only these entries in Chain DOCKER (4 references): 
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:27017
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.3           tcp dpt:http-alt (sorry the terrible formatting, dunno how to make line breaks in comment field:-)

Comment: just to mention, inside the db container, the mongo client runs nicely, as well: docker-compose exec db /bin/bash
root@c3828d1a0e6c:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("8dbd5e00-f2a4-4c8e-a7dc-0bb04cdd81d7") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.1

Comment: also just notice that some docker process is actually holding the port 8080 : sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080
[sudo] password for ***:
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      5855/docker-proxy